# Apache Alias file could not be found

Tags: apache-2.4

I want to set up an alias in apache like this:

http://example.com/deploy

I do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        Alias   "/deploy/" "/var/www/deploy/"

        <Directory "/var/www/deploy/">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Here the folders:

```
[root@asd]# ls -lisaR /var/www/deploy/
/var/www/deploy/:
total 4
    125 0 drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 23 Jan  9 13:20 .
8887786 0 drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root   47 Jan  9 13:19 ..
 148408 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 19 Jan  9 13:17 index.php
[root@asd]#
```

I get always a 404 error.
The error says this:

> Not Found The requested URL /deploy was not found on this server.

Comment: What about dropping the trailing slashes? `Alias "/deploy" "/var/www/deploy"`

Comment: Also, depending on your OS, it's possible that you need to modify your SELinux configuration.

Comment: I tried without trailing slashes is not working. I have a CentOS system from aws ec2. I got not a 403 error so I think it is not an SELinux issue.

Comment: If you ask for `index.php` file directly, does it work? Something like `http://example.com/deploy/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Apache version 2.4.19 or later you can just write in configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        Alias    "/deploy/"
        <Directory "/var/www/deploy/">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Also you should verify if **mod_alias** is enabled, typing **sudo a2enmod mod_alias**
If still doesn't solve your problem you could try to use **mod_rewrite**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName undesired.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com notthis.example.com

  Redirect "/" "http://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Example source from: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: I tried this solution in Apache 2.4 and it fails. Alias must have two arguments. I added the second argument. I still get the error mentioned in the question: All attempts to access an alias come up file not found.

Comment: I'm running Apache 2.4.54 and ever since the upgrade to the 2.4 versions on Ubuntu, my aliases have stopped working in spite having the same VirtualHost settings shown here. I've confirmed the mod_alias is running, I tried it with and without quotes but continue to get File Not Found. The Apache error log shows nothing other than the restarts after each change.

Comment: idk for other platforms, but on ubuntu it's `a2enmod alias`

Answer (score 1):

I am using Apache 2.4.25.

You can list **available** modules:

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-available/
```

List **enabled** modules:

```
ls /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
```

I load the [Alias module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) like this:

```
a2enmod alias
```

Then as mentioned in [Felipes answer](https://serverfault.com/a/948914/190972), update the virtualhost file with something like...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        Alias    "/foo/" "/var/www/foo/"
        <Directory "/var/www/foo/">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now reload apache2 to reflect changes made to the virtualhost file:

```
systemctl reload apache2
```